# What are the ways to display text in android?

Tags: android

I m beginner of android  . .
I have an application in which there are various activities on which different text is appearing. In my application i need all the text in this app. I got 60% of the text in the app that is set using `setText()` method . But still some text is visible but i dont know how they have displayed this text.

SO what i want is that, the methods or any other ways in android that enables us to display the text in our activity.

For more clarification i show u an image of app:

[image]

I need to know how these texts are been set  . .
It will be helpful if list out methods which are used to set text .

Comment: You will have to use selectors and specify seperate drawable for android:state_focused,android:state_pressed

Answer (score 0):

you can display text in a textview, via java or xml, or you can use canvas.drawText().

these are the simple two... there is also the Toast for quick pop-up text, and dialogs which are toasts with buttons... there are several ways you can display text. the image above, is an image of text set to the background of a tab, or the src/background of an imageview...

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you have to ways of showing text:

1. Using an element that allows showing text: Button, TextView

for these guys, you'll normally use the .setText setter that you probably already know.

1. You can show an image or use an image as background for a element: ImageView, ImageButton

for setting an image to an object, you'll normally use

- public void setImageResource (int resId)
- public void setImageBitmap (Bitmap bm)
- public void setImageDrawable (Drawable drawable)

The buttons above, mostly probably are set with an image.

For showing different images for different states (on tap, on select, etc) you'll have to define properties like the ones in the example below for the ImageButton:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

More information at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html